# when I try to add a second field set to an entity it doesn't show in the screens

Tags: set, field, spring-roo

I have six entities and I want to create two field sets from one to two others.  One field set is ONE_TO_MANY and I used field set in the ONE side to build the relation and the other is a MANY_TO_MANY and I tried the simplest example from Northwind and that didn't work, and I tried adding --joinTable, --joinColumns, etc. and that didn't work either.  Only the ONE_TO_MANY works and only one of those.

Is there a good example with Roo 2.0.0.RC1 that works? or a manual work around?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Spring Roo just generates and maintains the code that he knows. In this case, you are trying to create a really specific structure, so I recommend you to create it manually. Spring Roo doesnt't have any problem with custom code.

You could check the following repository where exists a lot of examples about relation management managed by Spring Roo or manually.

https://github.com/DISID/disid-proofs

Hope it helps,

Comment: Well yes I know, but the documentation does not say that only the first field set will be scaffolded and the field set MANY_TO_MANY will not...I think this is a defect.